# Can you find <td>s containing the same class using only a partial string?

Tags: javascript, html-table

My table's `<td>`s contains multiple classes. I would need to find every `<td>` that contains the given string.
For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="hello there">foo</td>
        <td class="hello here">bar</td>
        <td class="not hello">baz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would need to find every td containing "hello".
Can it be done? The simple `className ==` will only return exact matches. Of course.

Comment: Seems like I asked something very trivial, sorry. I just couldn't find it. Not like it would hurt (people can just find the answer on this site through Google.) Thank you.

Comment: No worry. You could accept the first to have answered and this will be finished without fuss :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) is for:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hello');
```

This'll select any elements that have the class `hello`.

**Note:** The `class` attribute contains a space separated list of class names.

---

If you need to support IE8 and below, use this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    helloElements = [],
    i = elements.length;

for (i--) {
    if ( ~(' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' hello ') ) {
        helloElements.push(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AJEsp/

---

As per @mplungjan's suggestion, here's a short explanation of the bitwise tilde (~) trick:

The `indexOf` function returns an integer with the position of the found substring, so that `'abc'.indexOf('b')` will return `1`, `'abc'.indexOf('c')` will return `2`, and so forth. If the substring is not found, it will return `-1`.

The `~` character is one of [the bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) whcih inverts all the bits. Sidestepping the complicated issue of how exactly this happens, all we need to know now is that `~-1` returns `0`, while using the tilde on *anything else* would return a truthy value.

So, `~'str'.indexOf('substring')` can be treated as a Boolean of whether the substring was found.

Comment: But only supported in IE in versions 9 and above. http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Added method for IE8-

Comment: @mplungjan - I think this answer is not the right place to delve into bitwise operator explanation, but I added a short intro on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. No worries about IE. (Who uses IE anyway? Who does, deserves a broken website IMHO. :))

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var cur = tds[i];
    var the_class = cur.className;
    if (the_class.split(" ").indexOf("hello") > -1) {
        // cur has the class "hello"
    }
}
```

There are other solutions though.

You can use the `.classList` attribute that isn't completely supported yet - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList .

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName .

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll .

```
var td_with_class = document.querySelectorAll("td.hello");
```

Comment: IE8- does not support `indexOf` on arrays.

Comment: @JosephSilber Are you really gonna bring that up? I don't think every answer on SO that uses `indexOf` should have to link to a polyfill for `indexOf`. If someone has a problem in IE8/IE7 with the use of `indexOf`, then they can look it up...

Comment: @ianpgall - Sorry, didn't mean to start a war. Just that this can easily be accomplished by using `indexOf` on the string...

Comment: @JosephSilber No problem, I just see this a lot. I mean, it is clearly needed for < IE9, but there are so many browser inconsistencies that answers would have so much extra content to accompany every situation. Using `indexOf` on the string would not work, in the case that a `<td>` has a class "hellothere", which would match but not be correct. I thought of that a long time ago, but that's why I go with splitting by " ".

Comment: @ianpgall - See my answer. It won't match on `hellothere`. It's a neat trick I learned from [the jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L142-L153).

Comment: @JosephSilber Oh wow, never thought of that. I always wondered how to do it with just the string `className`, but for some reason never thought to prepend and append " " to the `className` value and checked that way. That's genius. Well, I guess jQuery genius...

Answer (score 1):

`class="hello there"` means that the td has two classes, `hello` and `there`.

So you could use

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  if (tds[i].className.match(/\bhello\b/i)){
    filtered.push(tds[i]);
  }
}
```

Use `RegExp` match and the `\b` symbol to match tds with that specified class. Alternatively, you can backwards filter starting with class and filtering by `tagName`:

```
var hellos = document.getElementsByClassName('hello'),
    filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < hellos.length; i++){
  if (hellos[i].tagName == 'TD'){
    filtered.push(hellos[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: An [example of both scenarios](http://jsfiddle.net/ETSYT/1/) in case anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

> Get all elements that have both the 'red' and 'test' classes
>
> ```
> document.getElementsByClassName('red test');
> ```

And to limit it to a certain node:

> Find all div elements that have a class of 'test'
>
> ```
> var tests = Array.prototype.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('test'), function(elem){
>     return elem.nodeName == 'TD';
> });
> ```

Comment: `Array.filter`? The `Array` constructor does not have a `.filter` static method.

Comment: Corrected to say Array.prototype.filter

Comment: In order to explicitly set the this-binding of the function invocation, you need to invoke the method via `.call()`: `Array.prototype.filter.call( ..., ... );`

Answer (score 0):

A general solution would be to get all items by tagname ("td"). Iterate over each item and determine if hello is a substring of the class attribute. Let me know if you need the code!

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly no one suggested jQuery [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Or just

```
var allHello = $("td.hello");
```

Comment: That's because there's no jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: That NEVER stopped anyone at SO ;))

Comment: I meant to include it in mine as the possibility of using jQuery, but forgot. And you probably want to update your selector in your edited answer to be `$("td.hello");`

Comment: I find it even more amazing someone takes time and effort to down vote a suggestion that makes perfect sense if the op is using jQuery anyway and is useful for people who come later who ARE using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) property.

```
elem.classList.contains( 'hello' )
```

returns whether the element contains the `"hello"` class.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/E7jMt/1/

`.classList` is implemented in all browsers (as of two days ago), but not in older version os IE (<10).